# cannot run java .class file from cmd

Tags: java, windows, shell, cmd, terminal

I have a java project with main class
in this path:

```
C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\
```

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

```
C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\src\tomer1>javac Test.java
```

I have checked and there are now two files:

```
Test.java, Test.class
```

I now try to run:

```
C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\src\tomer1>java Test
```

and get this error:

```
Error: couldn't find or load main class Test
```

I have defined PATH and CLASSPATH on my win8.

I have tried:

```
PS C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\src\tomer1> java tomer1.Test
Error: Could not find or load main class tomer1.Test
```

how can i fix this?

this is my code:

```
package tomer1;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("hi");

    }

}
```

Comment: That's not an error message. Please show the entire cmd conversation. Also your code might help us understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I added the error

Comment: what's your class package?

Comment: Please show your code. For all we know you could be using packages and might not be taking that into account.

Comment: do you have a `main` method in your class?

Comment: @NirLevy I added my code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added my code

Comment: You're forgetting the package -- that's part of the class's name space. In the future, search Google on your error message text as this is a very common problem, and with a little searching, I'll bet you would be able to easily solve this yourself.

Comment: I have tried `PS C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\src\tomer1> java tomer1.Test
Error: Could not find or load main class tomer1.Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go one dir up and run java with a package name:

```
C:\Users\tomer_000\Desktop\eclipse_tmp\src>java tomer1.Test.java
```

Comment: There must be 1000 dup's to this question. I'm not sure we need it to hang around.

Comment: sure, if you find a duplicate this one could be closed